# sqlite3_open - Can't open database

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have the following statement in my code:

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notebook.sqlite"]];
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
NSLog(@"open sqlite at %s",dbpath);
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &noteDB)==SQLITE_OK)
```

the output of `NSLog` is

> /Users/GinLin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/CE1BAB1C-3DEC-4A1D-A083-537B0B51C99D/Library/Documentation/Notebook.sqlite

but it doesn't seem to be opening my database.
And I cannot find the folder "Documentation" under "/CE1BAB1C-3DEC-4A1D-A083-537B0B51C99D/Library/".

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you meant to use `NSDocumentDirectory` not `NSDocumentationDirectory`, e.g.:

```
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must check if the DB path contains de file, else, copy the DB

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString* resourcePath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.db"];

    //Destination path
NSString *dbPath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.db"];
    //Find file
BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
if(success==YES){
    NSLog(@"File found");
}else{
    NSError* error;
    if(![fileMgr copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:dbPath error:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Can't copy");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"That's all :D");
    }
}
```